# how can I use boostrap with dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm new to this HTML CSS stuff and I like it. A few days ago I stumbled upon Bootstrap, and I liked it. How can I use it with dreamweaver ?

Comment: Just add a new page/site and choose bootstrap (Dreamweaver CC 2015)

Answer (score 1):

you can add the bootstrap files to your source (if you want to edit the bootstrap docs this is recomended) or just use the online-versions and apply the tags in the head part of your html document.

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and with this it should run no matter what IDE you use.

/S